# mysql_connect error

Tags: mysql, php, database

I've executed the below command in `sublime text editor`

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
```

And got the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/dieexit.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/dieexit.php on line 2
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: In which context did you execute the `mysql_connect` command?

Comment: i m using sublime text editor to write this code ....n even i m new to learn this language.....so i want to connect my database......so do search on google so i found this command to do ....but can't  so can anyone pls help me

Comment: And where is mysql_connect provided from in php?

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the error you got, it seems like the source of the problem is:

> You probably have a php7 in XAMPP - **mysql_* functions** have been removed in PHP7

**Suggested solution:**

**Instead of:**

```
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username)
```

**You can use:**

```
mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname , $mysql_username)
```

Or:

```
mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname);
```

**Some informative links:**

- [mysqli_connect manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
- [SO Q&A regarding mysql vs mysqli when using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548986/mysql-vs-mysqli-when-using-php)
- [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)